# How to customize solarize for gvim?

Tags: vim

I have solarized installed and looking great. The one thing I want to do differently is that I want a CursorLine that increases contrast, instead of decreasing it. It seems like I should simply be able to put...

```
hi CursorLine guibg=#000000
```

... in my .vimrc, and indeed, if I enter it as a command, it works as expected. But putting in the file itself has no effect. I've tried both before and after "colorscheme solarized."

Comment: The solution is obvious: edit the colorscheme directly.

Comment: Something in your `.vimrc` must be interfering. Are you sure you don't set the colorsheme somewhere else too? Try putting that line to the very end of `.vimrc`.

Comment: Putting it at the very end worked. I'm not sure what's interfering. I adapted my .vimrc from one I found online years ago, and I dont' understand all of it. But, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:hi` command must be issued after the *last* `colorscheme` command that is executed during startup. Since plugins shouldn't do this, it's likely in your `~/.vimrc`. Look closely; it's unnecessary overhead to configure multiple colorschemes; the last one wins, anyway.

If you switch colorschemes dynamically, you'd also need to hook into that via

```
autocmd ColorScheme * hi CursorLine guibg=#000000
```